# Not all named parameters have been set in specific conditions

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have using then following query in my Hibernate i.e createSQLQuery

```
SELECT to_char(dd, 'Mon YYYY') FROM generate_series('2013-01-01'::date, date_trunc('month', now()), '1 month') as dd
```

which produces output when run in PostgreSQL as

1. "Jan 2013" "Feb 2013" . . "Feb 2014"

However while using it through createSQLQuery as below , 
it throws "**org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [:date]**"

Please note that date has been used like '**2013-01-01'::date**

```
try{
            session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(); 
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT to_char(dd, 'Mon YYYY') FROM generate_series('2013-01-01'::date, date_trunc('month', now()), '1 month') as dd");
            monthList = new ArrayList<String>();            
            monthList = query.list();
            tx.commit();
        }
```

Please suggest

Comment: Try to replace the [Postgres-specific (`::`) type cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) with a SQL-standard one - `CAST ('2013-01-01' AS DATE)` (or `DATE '2013-01-01'`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to replace the [Postgres-specific (::) type cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) with a SQL-standard one - `CAST ('2013-01-01' AS DATE)` (or `DATE '2013-01-01'`).

Comment: The line-break after 'CAST' in your post is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `:` characters in your SQL `String`, the parser will treat them as named parameters unless you escape them. The alternative `CAST` syntax suggested by [Milen A. Radev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15785/milen-a-radev) is nice for that particular case, but there are cases where there is no trivial alternative syntax, e.g. array slicing:

```
SELECT count(*), 
    array_to_string((array_agg(id order by whenCreated desc))[1\\:20], ',') ids 
FROM …
```

Different versions of the parser `org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterParser` allow different escaping of `:` characters, but they all seem to recognise `\:`, so that's what I've used. Some versions also allow `::` to represent an escaped `:`, but I've not tested that.

Note that as usual, you'll also need to escape your `\` in your Java String, so the escape sequence is `\\:` for any `:` character that you don't want to represent a named parameter.

Comment: Ha! I can't believe I didn't think to try that. The casting solution is more readable for my particular need, but quoting the ':' works too.